# How can I explicitly apply default browser rendering color for anchor elements with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a table built with a column of links using the default browser rendering for anchors. There is a search which uses XSL to display search results. However, the XSL needs a specific CSS class to render the anchor elements.

I am trying to match the CSS class with the color the browser uses for anchor elements. However, through all this trial and error, I can't get a match on shading. I initially tried color: blue in the CSS class but that's not even close, it comes out purplish.

If I try to ignore color: in the CSS class, the link comes out black.

I guess what I was wondering if it's possible to set the color in CSS to something like this...

color: Use browser anchor default

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default colour of a link according to browser styles is: `rgb(0, 102, 204)`

If you don't alter the CSS, this would be the default. If you are seeing something slightly purple, I'm guessing this is because it has been visited and receives dedicated styling.

This can be amended in your CSS by targeting `a:visited { }`

[image: Default browser link colour (computed)]

**EDIT**: If you need to remove a style which has overridden the browser default, you could also use the 'revert' property; e.g.  `color: revert` (which is also part of the `all` property). See the support [here on caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-revert-value), and more details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert).

[image: Reverting CSS]

Comment: correct, also in chrome seems that they use "`-webkit-link` color" https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA5dt.jpg this info I found it throught devtools

Comment: thanks so much. That matches it. The blue=purple is weird as it basically builds these links from scratch. I'll mess around with that part more by setting color:blue on some plain text. See what happens.

Comment: This is only the default color in Chrome. This isn't the same as resetting applied CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default color with `getComputedStyle`

```js
var el = document.createElement("a");
el.href = "#";
document.body.appendChild(el);
console.log(getComputedStyle(el).color);
document.body.removeChild(el);
```

Node: the element needs to be part of the document, otherwise color is an empty string

Comment: i didn't know about that method. That is cool that it will derive the color, even for non-explicitly set elements.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the color, you cn use this script in JS:

```
const linkColor = document.getElementById('link').style.Color
```

and this HTML Code

```
<a href="#" id='link' hidden>
```

To try it, you can use this html-page:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" id='link' hidden>
<script>
console.log(document.getElementById('link').style.Color)</script>
<body>
</html>
```

This should log the link-color in the console.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. I am able to match other elements this way.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're targeting modern browsers, and your goal is to REMOVE any styling already applied, you can use the "all" property.

```
a.specificClass {
   all: initial;
}
```

**This will reset all properties to their browser default.**

If all you want is to change the color, you can still use the `initial` or `unset` values.

```
a.specificClass {
   color: initial;
}
```

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) - [Can I Use (All)](https://caniuse.com/css-all)

Comment: So initial is always the browser default? Thanks so much.

Comment: Correct it works for any property (but NOT in IE <= 11).  Eg: `overflow: initial;` or `"width: initial;` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp